# nokogiri move A tag if it breaks the parent node text

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I check the text of each terminal node. The A tag breaks the text, so the text doesn't match /PART/. Is it possible to move the position of A tag:

```
<P><FONT SIZE=3><B>PA<A NAME="name"></A>RT</B></FONT></P>
```

to

```
<P><FONT SIZE=3><B><A NAME="name"></A>PART</B></FONT></P>
```

But if the A tag doesn't break the text of the parent node, I will leave as it.

I don't know how to tell if a tag breaks the text of the parent node or not.

This is the code I tried, without condition on if a tag breaks the text.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'awesome_print'

html = '<P><FONT SIZE=3><B>PA<A NAME="name"></A>RT II</B></FONT></P>
<P><FONT SIZE=3><B><A NAME="name"></A>PART II</B></FONT></P>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('a').each do |n|
    text = n.parent.text
    n.parent.replace n
    n.parent.content = text
end
```

output

```
 <p><font size="3">PART II</font></p>
 <p><font size="3">PART II</font></p>
```

Comment: I updated what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the previous text to the other side of the a you can do:

```
a.add_next_sibling(a.previous) if a.previous && a.previous.text?
```